# Using "any" operator in dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the "any" operator inside "filter" in dplyr package
like this:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 iris %>%
   as_tibble() %>%
   filter( any(Species == "setosa",
               Species == "versicolor") )

# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

for some reason the filter is ignored because iris contains 150 rows.

However when the "|" operator is used the correct number of rows is returned:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 iris %>%
   as_tibble() %>%
   filter( Species == "setosa" | 
             Species == "versicolor" )

# A tibble: 100 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Is it possible to make the code work using the "any" operator with dplyr filter?

Rafael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What purpose does `any` serve in your code? I think you just want

```
… %>% filter(Species == "setosa" | Species == "versicolor")
```

Or

```
… %>% filter(Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"))
```

In either case, the expression inside `filter` returns a *vector* corresponding to the rows inside your data frame. By contrast, `any` returns a *single* value, either `TRUE` or `FALSE` so it will either filter *all* rows, or none.

Comment: OK. Thanks to your explanation i now understand why "any" doesn't work. indeed i wanted to achieve "… %>% filter(Species == "setosa" | Species == "versicolor")" but used any because it is more nicely vertically indented. as can can be seen in my post in the 2 pieces of code..

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by simply adding `rowwise()` before filter.

```
testdf <- data.frame(a = c(1:10), b = c(10:1))

testdf |>
  rowwise() |>
  filter(any(a == 5, b == 9))
```