# How do I keep every ID which meet a condition at least once?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

How do I keep every ID which meet a condition at least once?

I have a df with repeated measurements. Now i want to keep all rows of the individuals that meet a condition at least once. I tried a dplyr group_by but i always only end up with the rows that fulfill the condition and loose all other measurements of that individual.

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(category=="blood") %>%
  ungroup()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dat1 %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(any(category == "blood"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check below link for more information:

[Using "any" operator in dplyr filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080811/using-any-operator-in-dplyr-filter)

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(condition)) %>%
  ungroup()
```